# how to set NOCOMPRESS flag on a file in btrfs?

Tags: btrfs, compression

according to https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression#How_do_I_enable_compression.3F  there exist a "[NOCOMPRESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuKoi.png)" flag, how do i set the NOCOMPRESS flag on a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could certainly have stolen my answer for yourself :)

the easiest is `btrfs property set $THING compression none` and a defrag to uncompress it. using `btrfs property` to set the `+c` force-compression flag is the most flexible, as you can specify a compression type to force, where using `chattr` it defaults to using `zlib`.

Comment: he's asking about setting `NOCOMPRESS` and you reply `+c` which is about setting compression, not unsetting ut

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `chattr +m 'FILE'`

> m      A file with the 'm' attribute is excluded from compression on file systems that support per-file compression.

The +c option mentioned by @Andrew Keech is the opposite.

Note, however, that there are mount options in btrfs that will disregard the NOCOMPRESS flag, as mentioned in the docs you provided.